# Servlet returns response as null to jsp jdbc request.

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to fetch details of a user based on username and password. The UserControllerServlet receives a response from UserUtil class (helper class) and prints the details on redirect.jsp.

The problem is when I enter username and password from the login page, the Servlet does not redirect to the redirect.jsp page. All I get is blank.

I tried printing reponse from UserUtil in Servlet and the object only returns null.

**File: login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/Login_Test/UserControllerServlet" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="login">
        <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>User name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Password:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="password"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="save"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**File: User.java**

```
package com.logintest.example;
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String usertype;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUsertype() {
        return usertype;
    }
    public void setUsertype(String usertype) {
        this.usertype = usertype;
    }


    public User(String username, String password, String usertype) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.usertype = usertype;
    }
    public User() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", usertype=" + usertype + "]";
    }

}
```

**File:UserUtil.java**

```
package com.logintest.example;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class UserUtil {
     DataSource dataSource;

    public UserUtil(DataSource theDataSource){
        dataSource = theDataSource;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() throws Exception{
        List<User> user = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try{
            conn=dataSource.getConnection();
            String sql="select * from user_login";
            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            //process resultset
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String username = rs.getString(1);
                String password = rs.getString(2);
                String usertype = rs.getString(3);

                //create user object
                User user1 = new User(username,password,usertype);

                //add to list
                user.add(user1);
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally{
            close(conn,stmt,rs);
        }

        return user;
    }

    private void close(Connection conn, Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) {
        try
        {
            if(rs!=null)
            {
                rs.close();
            }
            if(stmt!=null)
            {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if(rs!=null)
            {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

    }

    public User getUser(String username, String password) throws Exception{
        User user1 = null;
        Connection conn=null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String username1=null;
        String password1=null;
        String usertype1=null;
        try
        {
            conn=dataSource.getConnection();
            String sql = "select * from user_type where username=? and password=?";
            stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, username);
            stmt.setString(2, password);
            rs=stmt.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                 username1 = rs.getString(1);
                 password1 = rs.getString(2);
                 usertype1 = rs.getString(3);
                 user1 = new User(username1,password1,usertype1);

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("User not found: ");
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {}
        finally{
            close(conn,stmt,rs);
        }
        return user1;
    }

}
```

**File: UserControllerServlet.java**

```
package com.logintest.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@WebServlet("/UserControllerServlet")
public class UserControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UserUtil userUtil;

    @Resource(name="jdbc/sample")
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init();
        try{
            userUtil = new UserUtil(dataSource);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try
        {
            String command = request.getParameter("command");
            switch(command)
            {
            case "login":
                login(request,response);
                break;

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

    }

    private void login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

    throws Exception{


        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");

        User user1 = userUtil.getUser(username, password);

        request.setAttribute("USER", user1);


        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/redirect.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

Table- **user_login**:

```
+-------------+-----------------+----------+
| username    | password        | usertype |
+-------------+-----------------+----------+
| sample_user | sample_password | employee |
+-------------+-----------------+----------+
```

[login.jsp screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB4zk.png)

[this is the response that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/886tI.png)

Comment: Anyone who writes `catch (Exception e) { }` (i.e. empty catch block) should be slapped. Anyone who writes it after a block with JDBC commands should be publicly flogged on the main square. I.e. put at least `e.printStackTrace();` into your catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried printing reponse from UserUtil in Servlet and the object only returns null.

In your code the datasources unable to get the connection, that's why it shows as null.

In your UserUtil.java file, catch the exception. You can clearly identify the reason for particular exception.

```
catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();
}
    finally{
        close(conn,stmt,rs);
    }
    return user1;
```

Send me the feedback :)